# Adding advertising to iPhone Application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, admob

I wanted to integrate advertising platform into my iPhone App and I was wondering which one is better to use Admob or iAd and why?

Thanks in advance,

Sarah

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, and is quite subjective. You should recast it in terms of which API's are easier learn/use, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for comment, do you recommend another place where I can post my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well thanks to new terms and conditions your only option at this very moment is iAds.